# Should I offer to give a presentation in a postdoc interview if not requested in the invitation?

Tags: postdocs, presentation, interview

I was invited to a 30 minute interview for a postdoc position. The only details given about the interview was to learn about my interests and background as well as learn about the lab I am interviewing.

Even though not requested, should I prepare a 10 minute or less presentation summarizing my research background and ask if they would like me to present during the interview? My field is computer science, and the interview will be via video chat (e.g., Zoom).

Comment: Whether you call it presentation or not it is more or less what the interview is. So certainly you have to be prepared anyway. I doubt that an interview like that is just chatting without support material.

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be worth it to develop such a thing as a backup, but I wouldn't offer it unasked.

If they already have an idea of the things they need to know and have questions ready, then I doubt that it would help and, unless it is "just right" (whatever that means), it could hurt.

Give them what they ask for.

But preparing a presentation will probably help you prepare and give you a bit of practice in presenting yourself. If nothing else, it gives you sentences and phrases to drop in as needed in the interview.